# How to Log SQL Loader Error in database table

Tags: oracle, error-handling, controls, sql-loader

I have a control file using which I will loading some data into a table following is the  control file

```
    LOAD DATA
INFILE  'D:\prova2new.txt'
BADFILE 'D:\Prova6.bad'
discardmax 1
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE tact_gfp_customers_ba_bck
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(CID  CHAR NULLIF CID=BLANKS,
CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR NULLIF CUSTOMER_NAME=BLANKS,
ARBOR_BA CHAR NULLIF ARBOR_BA=BLANKS,
PROXY_NUMBER CHAR NULLIF PROXY_NUMBER=BLANKS,
DD_STATUS CHAR NULLIF DD_STATUS=BLANKS,
DDS_DATE DATE NULLIF DDS_DATE=BLANKS,
PRIMARY_FLAG_BANK CHAR NULLIF PRIMARY_FLAG_BANK=BLANKS,
LAST_UPD_DATE DATE NULLIF LAST_UPD_DATE=BLANKS, 
BRANCH_NUMBER CHAR NULLIF BRANCH_NUMBER=BLANKS,
BANK_NUMBER CHAR NULLIF BANK_NUMBER=BLANKS,
ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR NULLIF ACCOUNT_NUMBER =BLANKS,
ACCOUNT_NAME CHAR NULLIF ACCOUNT_NAME =BLANKS,
IBAN  CHAR NULLIF IBAN=BLANKS,
ACCOUNT_HOLDER  CHAR NULLIF ACCOUNT_HOLDER =BLANKS,
ACCOUNT_SIGNER  CHAR NULLIF ACCOUNT_SIGNER =BLANKS,
HOLDER_REG_NO CHAR NULLIF HOLDER_REG_NO = BLANKS,
SIGNER_FISCAL_CODE CHAR NULLIF SIGNER_FISCAL_CODE=BLANKS
)
```

Using the below command I am using this control file to load data

```
sqlldr userid=COMP/COMP99@dw12_cind_np control=D:\V_CUSTOMERS_BA.ctl , log=D:\ErrorInsert.log
```

Now the problem is I am running this SqlLoader command using a batch file in a seperate server which I don't have any access to. To see the error log everytime I have to request the Server Support Team to provide me the latest log. I want to make this process easier by logging aby SQL Error that the SQL Loader will encounter in my Database table. So that I could check the error by a simple select.

How can I insert the SQL Loader Error log into a DB table?

Comment: Is using External Tables instead of sqlldr an option for you ? If yes then you can use insert into this external table and user error_logging_clause

Comment: @Ankit - errors that prevent data appearing in the external table in the first place still get logged to a file on the server though, don't they?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you use error_logging_clause all the records which are not inserted in the external table can be logged into a separate table and your issue will be resolved. Your thoughts ?

Comment: @Ankit - I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. The log and bad files have to be in Oracle directories, so they're on the file system not in the database. Which error logging clause do you mean? Are you suggesting loading the data as an external table that won't get errors (all big varchars, maybe) and then recording the errors when you try to copy data from the external table to a real one?

Comment: I use a scripting language, Python in this case, to parse the log file.

Comment: @Ben Can you please give an example. How could I embedd something like PHP/Python in a control file. If that is what you meant.

Comment: @Ankit external table I cannot use here. Is there any way to design the .ctl file in a way that it directly insert any error in a table the way it inserts data into a table.